# Access Denied on Master Detail record

Tags: profile, master-detail, permission-sets, guest-user

Here is my situation.
I created the following objects as System Administrator.

Object A - custom objects with only standard fields
Object B - custom object with only a Master-Detail field to the Object A and the Sharing setting is set to Read/Write.

I have created Permission Set that gives read/write/delete/modify All permissions to Object A.
I am creating a standard user and assign him that permission set. I am not using any profiles other than the Admin profile and I don't have any role hierarchy to the org.

From what I understand from the Salesforce documentation the permissions for the detail records are inherited from the master.

However when I am logged in as the standard user I cannot create/edit/delete any detail records.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Check your Org wide Setting for the child object, As per docs When a custom object is on the detail side of a master-detail relationship with a standard object, its organization-wide default is set to Controlled by Parent and it is not editable. Since both the child and parent are custom objects the parent need not be controlling the child access ( unless you explicitly specify)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues at play here: record sharing or "ownership" (controlled by "sharing settings" and org-wide defaults), and CRUD permissions.  They are different.  It sounds like you set up record sharing correctly, but failed to grant CRUD access to the detail object.  In the permission set, navigate to the Object Settings for the detail object and make sure the appropriate Read/Edit/Update/Delete flags are ticked, along with the field (FLS) permissions you desire.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By setting the flags to the detail object I can successfully create/edit/delete it. I was under the impression though that CRUD permissions were being inherited as well from the master object. Thanks for clearing that out.